# TFS 2015 Flowdock Service hook behind a proxy

Tags: tfs

I have created a new `flowdock` service hook that sends a chat message when a pull request has been created.  The TFS server is behind a corporate proxy so I have set up the proxy config in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 14.0\Application Tier\Web Services\web.config`. The test button works and sends a test message though to my flow.  When I try try it for real and create a pull request the hook fails with:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> 
    System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (407) 
    Proxy Authentication Required.
```

It looks like the hook is taking a different root.

Any idea if there are any config files that require the proxy setting?

Comment: How did you set up the proxy config in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 14.0\Application Tier\Web Services\web.config?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I raised a ticket with Microsoft in the end and they gave me a solution that partially worked.

By adding the proxy config to the web config in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 14.0\Application Tier\Message Queue and C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 14.0\Application Tier\Web Services_areas then resetting the background job agent service I started ti get intermittent result.

I noticed while running process monitor that most of the work was coming out of TfsJobAgent.exe I added the proxy setting to C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 14.0\Application Tier\TFSJobAgent\TfsJobAgent.exe.config, restarted the service and now I seem to get persistent success when the service hook fires.

Comment: I have also set this for the TFS agents. Not sure if this is really necessary but I was a bit desperate and didn't want to spend more time on this,

Comment: I set proxy in above web configs and restart the service "Visual Studio Team Foundation Background Job Agent". It works! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may try the code below:

```
 <system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
    <proxy usesystemdefault="True" proxyaddress="http://<yourproxy:port#" bypassonlocal="True"/>
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```